# Local extrema in f(x,y)=z data

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, data-science

I have a data file with `z=f(x,y)` data in three columns. I am trying to find local minima in `z`.

Unfortunately, the data is not on a grid, otherwise I would have used SciPy's `argrelextrema`. Is there any way to find the positions of my minima?

Comment: Not without assumptions about your function (except you only want to find the min-val in that column what i don't think is your task here).

Comment: What would be suitable assumptions? I know that the function is sufficiently smooth over all my data points

Comment: We don't know your data. You have to decide on that! [Why needed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularization_(mathematics)).

Comment: I'm not sure if that would suit your needs but you could use scipy's `griddata` ([doc here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html)) to interpolate your data on a grid and then use `argrelextrema` on it.